# A question on Rudin's "proof" of the associativity of the convolution of two measures

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups

### **Background**

Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group and $M(G)$ the Banach space of all complex Radon measures on $G$. The convolution of two complex Radon measures 
 $\mu, \lambda\in M(G)$ is defined by specifying a linear functional on $C_0(G)$ (and invoking Riesz representation theorem) as follows:

$$\int_G\phi\,\mathrm{d}(\mu*\nu)=\int_G\int_G\phi(xy)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)\,\mathrm{d}\nu(y)$$ for $\phi\in C_0(G)$.

However in Rudin's *[Fourier Analysis on Groups](http://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/iosevich/rudingroupsbook.pdf)* (see page 14 for details) to prove that the convolution of measures are associative (see **Theorem 1.3.2(b)**) he uses the following definition convolution of two measures of $M(G)$ as follows,

> **Definition 1.** Let $\mu,\lambda\in M(G)$ then the set function $\mu\ast \lambda$ is defined as follows, $$(\mu \ast \lambda)(E):=(\mu\times \lambda)(E_{(2)})$$for each Borel set $E$ in $G$ where $\mu\times \lambda$ denotes the product measure on $G\times G$ and, $$E_{(2)}:=\{(x,y)\in G\times G:x+y\in E\}$$

To prove associativity of convulotion, he generalizes the above definition to $n$-measures as follows,

> **Definition 2.** Let $\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n\in M(G)$ then the set function $(\mu_1\ast\ldots\ast\mu_n)$ is defined as follows, $$(\mu_1\ast\ldots\ast\mu_n)(E):=(\mu_1\times\ldots\times\mu_n)(E_{(n)})$$for each Borel set $E$ in $G$ where $(\mu_1\times\ldots\times\mu_n)$ denotes the product measure on $G^n$ and, $$E_{(n)}:=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in G^n:x_1+\ldots+x_n\in E\}$$

and simply says that the associativity of measures follows by Fubini's Theorem.

### **Questions**

- Let's take $n=3$ and consider the then the first problem that I am facing is regarding the definition of $\mu_1\ast (\mu_2\ast \mu_3)$ in accordance with **Definition 2**.

  Sure,by applying **Definition 1** we can say that,$$(\mu_1\ast (\mu_2\ast \mu_3))(E):=(\mu_1\times (\mu_2\ast \mu_3))(E_{(2)})$$but then what? Similar is the problem with the definition of $(\mu_1\ast \mu_2)\ast \mu_3$.
- How can we use Fubini's theorem to prove the result?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\lambda,\mu, \nu\in M(G)$. Let $\alpha:G\times G\rightarrow G$ be the group operation +. Let $E$ be a Borel measurable set.
\begin{align}
(\lambda*\mu)*\nu(E)&=(\lambda*\mu)\times \nu(\alpha^{-1}(E))\\
&=\iint \chi_E(x+z)d(\lambda*\mu)(x)d\nu(z)
\end{align}
Now for each $z\in G$, let $E-z=\{e-z:e\in E\}$. We then have
\begin{align}
\int \chi_E(x+z)d(\lambda*\mu)(x)&=\int \chi_{E-z}(x)d(\lambda*\mu)\\
&=(\lambda*\mu)(E-z)\\
&=(\lambda\times \mu)(\alpha^{-1}(E-z))\\
&=\iint\chi_{E-z}(x+y)d\lambda(x)d\mu(y)\\
&=\iint\chi_{E}(x+y+z)d\lambda(x)d\mu(y)\\
\end{align}
We conclude that
$$(\lambda*\mu)*\nu(E)=\iiint\chi_E(x+y+z)d\lambda(x)d\mu(y)d\nu(z)$$
Similarly one can prove the following equality by using Fubini's Theorem:
$$\lambda*(\mu*\nu)(E)=\iiint\chi_E(x+y+z)d\lambda(x)d\mu(y)d\nu(z)$$
which suggests that convolution of measures is associative.